# How to find all columns contains string and put in a new columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I was wondering how could I find all values that start with 'orange' from all the columns and parse it into new columns.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'a':["mango 2","mango 3",'apple 3', 'orange 1345','orange 2456','banana 1', "watermelon 2","mango 2","mango 3"],
                    'b':["mango 2","mango 3",'apple 3','banana 1', "watermelon 2", 'orange 41134','orange 22145',"mango 2","mango 3"],
                    'c':['apple 3',"mango 2","mango 3" ,"mango 2","mango 3",'banana 1', "watermelon 2",'orange 2222','orange 2341'],
                    'd':["mango 2","mango 3","mango 2","mango 3",'apple 3','banana 1', "watermelon 2","mango 2","mango 3",'orange 9087','orange 0021'],
                    'e':['apple 3', 'orange 1','orange 2','banana 1', "watermelon 2"]})
```

expected output :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'category':['orange 1345','orange 2456','orange 41134','orange 22145','orange 2222','orange 2341','orange 9087','orange 0021','orange 1','orange 2'}]
```

Comment: "parse it into new columns" how?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there expected output?

Comment: @AndrejKesely done edit my question with expected output

Comment: @HenryEcker I mean extract it into new columns, like ({'category':['orange 1345','orange 2456','orange 41134','orange 22145','orange 2222','orange 2341','orange 9087','orange 0021','orange 1','orange 2'}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) then filter by [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df1 = data.stack()
df1 = (
    df1[df1.str.contains('^orange', regex=True)]
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .to_frame('category')
)
```

`df1`:

```
       category
0   orange 1345
1  orange 41134
2   orange 2222
3   orange 9087
4      orange 1
5   orange 2456
6  orange 22145
7   orange 2341
8   orange 0021
9      orange 2
```

---

Or [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) for same order as OP:

```
df1 = data.melt()['value']
df1 = (
    df1[df1.str.contains('^orange', regex=True)]
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .to_frame('category')
)
```

`df1`:

```
       category
0   orange 1345
1   orange 2456
2  orange 41134
3  orange 22145
4   orange 2222
5   orange 2341
6   orange 9087
7   orange 0021
8      orange 1
9      orange 2
```

---

regex `^orange`:

1. `^` asserts position at start of a line
2. `orange` matches the characters `orange` literally (case sensitive)

Comment: It gave me an error in return, it say AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'stack'

Comment: `data` is a DataFrame in your question. Your error implies that it is a python dictionary. You should be doing these operations on a DataFrame.

Comment: btw, how make it index accordingly using their previous index? 

for example extract all value that start with 'b' then put into new column according to their previous index:

df = pd.DataFrame({'b':['b','a','a','c','c'],
                  'c':['a','b','b','c','c'],
                 'd':['a','a','a','b','b']})

output : df = pd.DataFrame({'e':['b','b','b','b','b'],